# How to update my table with a new row using Ajax.beginform + partial view , Inside ym asp.net mvc web application

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have the following main view:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AssignCustomer", "Firewall", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = ??????????,
    LoadingElementId = "progress",
    HttpMethod= "POST",
    OnSuccess="submitform"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.FirewallCustomer.ID)


<div>
<span class="f">Customer Name</span>


@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName, new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("CustomerAutoComplete", "Firewall") })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName)




</div>


<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
<p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /></p>
<table  id ="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th class="f"> Customer Name </th>
    <th></th>

</tr></thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">

    @foreach(var info in Model.Firewall.FirewallCustomers.OrderBy(a=>a.CustomerName)){

        <tr id= "@info.CustomerName.Replace(" ", string.Empty)">


<td> @Html.ActionLink(info.CustomerName, "Index", "Customer", new {searchTerm=info.CustomerName},null)</td>
            <td> @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
 "DeleteCustomerFirewall", "Firewall",
new { firewallid = info.ID, customername = info.CustomerName},

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete " + info.CustomerName,
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

And when clicking on the ajax.beginform I need to insert the following partial view to be the first row of the table :-

```
@model TMS.Models.FirewallCustomer

        <tr id= "@Model.CustomerName.Replace(" ", string.Empty)">


<td> @Html.ActionLink(Model.CustomerName, "Index", "Customer", new {searchTerm=Model.CustomerName},null)</td>
            <td> @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
 "DeleteCustomerFirewall", "Firewall",
new { firewallid = Model.ID, customername = Model.CustomerName},

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete " + Model.CustomerName,
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})</td>
        </tr>
```

Can anyone advice what I should add inside the UpdateTargerID for the Ajax.BeginForm ; should this id be the table ID (id="myTable") or the Tbody ID (id= "tableBody") or another DOM element ?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with `Ajax.BeginForm`. My suggestion is use jquery's `$.ajax` or `$.post` and then on the success handler, prepend the data to your `tbody`

```
$.post("/FireWall/AssignCustomer", $("#formId").serialize(),
    function (data) {
      $(data).prependTo("table > tbody");
});
```

EDIT:

Not tested: Using `Ajax.BeginForm` try adding an empty first row `<tr id="firstRow"></tr>` in your table then use that as `targetId` with `InsertionMode.InsertAfter`

Comment: but could not i do the same using the Ajax.Beginform??

Comment: Try to target the tbody id and use insert after.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set UpdateTargetId and change your onsuccess method(deletionconfirmation) as follows

```
deletionconfirmation = function(data)
{
    $(data).prependTo("#tableBody > tbody");
//some other code.
}
```